# C# switch case Array contains string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, switch-statement, contains

Is it possible to look up if a string in contained in an Array, with a switch case?

```
 string text = "blalbac";
 string arr[] = {"a","b","c"};

  switch (text)
  {
    case arr.Contains(filename):
      //do..
      break;
  }
```

Comment: What is the relation between text, arr and filename?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16662631/switch-case-with-boolean

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], so we can see what `filename` is (for example).

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what you’re trying to do. Do you want something like

```
foreach(string item in arr)
{
    if(text.Contains(item))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```