# C# 8 switch expression for void methods

Tags: c#, switch-statement, c#-8.0, switch-expression

I'm aware of the `C# 8` `switch expression` syntax for methods that return a value or for property matching. But if we just need to switch on a string value and execute a method that returns nothing (no return type/void), then how do we go about it? I am thinking some form of Func but not sure of the exact syntax. I know we can do it the old way with regular case statements but was trying to see if we can achieve the same with the newer syntax.

Here's the example of the problem

```
switch (stringvalue)
{
    case "Add": Add(); break;
    case "Subtract": Subtract(); break;
}
```

could be like:

```
stringvalue switch
{
    "Add" => Add(),
    "Subtract" => Subtract()
}
// but this complains that there needs to be assignment on left side for this
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### TL;DR

***It is not possible.*** In `C# 8` `switch expression` cannot return `void`. It must return a value and this value must be consumed (assigned to a variable, passed as an argument to a method, returned as a result of a method, etc.). But there is a workaround. We can write a `switch expression` that returns a `delegate` (of type `Action`, for example) and then immediately invokes it:

```
(stringValue switch
 {
    "Add" => (Action) Add,
    "Subtract" => Subtract,
    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
 })();
```

Such approach also can be used with `expression bodied methods`. Here is [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3dpizR).

---

### Explanation

> Is this possible?

***In `C# 8` it is not possible. This limitation is described in `C# specification`.***

Lets refer to `C# specification`. From pages [`Recursive Pattern Matching - Switch Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#switch-expression) and [`Statements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#expression-statements) we can learn that:

- > The `switch_expression` is not permitted as an `expression_statement`.
- > An `expression_statement` evaluates a given expression. The value computed by the expression, if any, is discarded.

From these two statements we can conclude that `switch_expression` cannot be used in the context of `expression_statement`, and its result value ***cannot*** be discarded. The result value must be used, for example, it must be assigned to a variable, passed to a method as an argument or returned as a result of a method. Therefore compiler complains that `switch expression` cannot be used as a statement.

---

> if we just need to switch on a string value and execute a method that
> returns nothing (no return type/void), how do we go about it? I am
> thinking some form of Func but not sure of the exact syntax.

We can use the next approach: write a `switch expression` that returns a `delegate` and then immediately invokes it. For example:

```
(stringValue switch
 {
    "Add" => (Action) Add,
    "Subtract" => Subtract,
    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
 })();
```

This approarch also can be used to declare `expression bodied members`:

```
private static void Demo(string str) =>
    (str switch
     {
         "Add" => (Action) Add,
         "Subtract" => Subtract,
         _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
     })();
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3dpizR).

In my opinion such workaround looks ugly and personally I would prefer to use `switch-case` or `if-else` instead of such construction.

**Thanks to l33t's comment.** He pointed out that using such approach would cause each `case expression` suffer from very costly [delegate allocation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/know-thine-implicit-allocations/) (verified in `.NET 5`). So it is one more reason not to use this approach and prefer to use `switch-case` or `if-else`.

---

May be in future version of `C#` this limitation will be relaxed ([see this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#switch-expression)):

> The `switch_expression` is not permitted as an `expression_statement`.
>
> > We are looking at relaxing this in a future revision.

But I haven't found an appropriate proposal in [`csharplang repo`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/tree/master/proposals).

Comment: Unfortunately, this workaround is a performance killer. Do **NOT** use this! Each `case` expression will suffer from very costly [delegate allocation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/know-thine-implicit-allocations/) (verified in .NET 5).

Comment: @l33t Thanks. Good point. According to [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxAvo0a+gA4BOAlgG4BDAC4BTTHABsmCgBERAWwD21KHAAM6AM5Cu9ALwA+dtW1ctAdx5CAxgAt2DJMWdEARAEFgwV+kPoVcDD0nsAANA7OrgDKAK4ARjoC1kI+frEJXElC4U4uxAD6vgboQrZciuboAHYile5cAOYx8iJVQgDyMR0AZgBKAlUNIgCiAB7WIhxCPIpVdA5MtHQA3MjsqlLk6CF0eCy5RBvS6OmJybv7TEA===) delegate allocation will occur only once when an appropriate switch-branch is executed. But anyway I also prefer not to use such approach. My answer was more oriented to show why switch-expression didn't allow to return void.

Comment: Yes, it will allocate once *each time* the switch-branch is executed. So if you put it on a hot path there will be trouble :P

Comment: See this open proposal: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3038

Answer (score 7):

As Iliar told you, it can't be done. A workaround that I use sometimes is to add a local function that always returns true and I use a discard char in the switch assignment. I find this walkaround a bit clearer than the one using delegates.

For example you would add this to your code before the switch:

```
bool Add() { [HEREYOURCODEToAdd]; return true;}
bool Substract() { [HEREYOURCODETOSubstract]; return true;}
```

And then you will call it, like this:

```
_ = stringvalue switch {
    "Add" => Add(),
    "Substract" => Substract(),
};
```

I think this approach has some use cases. For example if you want to use tuple patterns in the switch it would be much more readable than many annidated ifs. This is a code that I'm using in which I consider this approach better than ifs:

```
           bool agregar(int índiceInicial, int índiceFinal) { visitasJson.Add(json[índiceInicial..índiceFinal]); return true; };
            _ = (índiceInicial, índiceFinal) switch {
                (0, -1) => agregar(índiceInicial + 1, índiceFinal - 3),
                (_, -1) => agregar(índiceInicial, índiceFinal - 1),
                (0, _) => agregar(índiceInicial + 5, índiceFinal),
                (_, _) => agregar(índiceInicial, índiceFinal),
            };
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you really want to use switch expression in your use case, just traditional way is much better.

All proposed solution like delegates, discard are workarounds.

You are trying to wrongly use switch expression.